# WSL2を用いてUbuntuを使用しDocker Desktopを起動したい

Tags: ubuntu, docker, wsl-2

#### 起きている問題

WSL2を用いてUbuntuを起動させています。

Docker Desktopを使用したいのですが、「*Starting the Docker Engine...*」というメッセージから切り替わらず、時間をおいていると「*WSL integration with distro "Ubuntu" unexpectedly stopped. Do you want to restart it?*」というエラーが発生します。

エラー文からUbuntuとDocker DesktopのWSL統合が失敗していると読み解けるのですが、解決方法がわからず困っています。

またこのエラーが発生すると以降WSL上でUbuntuを起動することができなくなります。（WSLとUbuntuを入れ直せばUbuntuは起動します。）

#### Ubuntuでのエラー文

```
接続済みの呼び出し先が一定の時間を過ぎても正しく応答しなかったため、接続できませんでした。または接続済みのホストが応答しなかったため、確立された接続は失敗しました。
Error code: Wsl/Service/0x8007274c
```

このエラーの原因と解決策を教えていただきたいです。

**使用環境**
Windows 11 バージョン22H2 ビルド 22621.3007
WSLカーネル 2024/02/07における最新
Ubuntu 22.04 Microsoft Storeよりダウンロード
Docker Desktop 4.27.1.0

#### 今回の事象の経緯

1. 2年前にWindows10の状態でDocker Desktopを導入する（導入後特に触れず）
2. 最近Dockerの勉強のために動かすが動作が重いためDocker Desktopを入れ直す
3. 「Starting the Docker Engine...」から動かなくなったため原因を調べWSLのバージョンが古いため動かないとわかり、WSL2を導入しようとするがWindows10Homeでは厳しいとのことでWindows11にバージョンアップする
4. バージョンアップ完了後WSL2を導入しUbuntuを動かそうとするも上記のエラー（Ubuntuでのエラー文と同じです）が発生し動かない
5. 以下のサイトのWindows10でのやり方を参考にWSLとUbuntuを導入したところUbuntuの起動には成功したがDocker Desktopは解決せず（wsl --installを使用するやり方の場合4番と同じくうまくいきませんでした）
   参考サイト：https://www.kagoya.jp/howto/it-glossary/develop/wsl2_linux/
6. 質問するに至る

もし解決するために必要なことで記載がないことがありましたらコメントで教えてください。
初学者故、初歩的なことを聞いてしまうでしょうがご協力お願いします。